# How to suppress sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine logging to stdout?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am running an python app in Windows 7 which uses sqlalchemy.

In the console (DOS prompt) I can see a lot of output from the sqlalchemy module e.g.

```
2013-09-16 13:59:20,158 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine UPDATE DATA SET qty=?, price=?
```

I want to continue to log these messages in the log file but would like to suppress them from printing to the stdout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding a `FileHandler` to the `sqlalchemy` logger and setting its `propagate` attribute to `False`, for example like this:

```
import logging

sqla_logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy')
sqla_logger.propagate = False
sqla_logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('/path/to/sqla.log'))
```

Alternatively you can use a logging configuration API (e.g. `logging.config.dictConfig()`) to do the same thing as above.

Answer (score 5):

If you want your `RootLogger`to print the logs, remove the handlers from SQLAlchemy:

```
sqla_logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine')
for hdlr in sqla_logger.handlers:
    sqla_logger.removeHandler(hdlr)
```

Tested with SQLAlchemy 0.9